# Matlab random sample of a dataset

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I have a dataset (Data) which is a vector of, let's say, 1000 real numbers. I would like to extract at random from Data 100 times 10 contiguous numbers. I don't know how to use Datasample for that purpose.
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 3):

You can just pick 100 random numbers between 1 and 991:

```
I = randi(991, 100, 1)
```

Then use them as the starting points to index 10 contiguous elements:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)(Data(x:x+9)), I, 'uni', false))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a snipet, but instead of using Datasample, I used `randi` to generate random indexes.

```
n_times = 100;
l_data = length(Data);

index_random = randi(l_data-9,n_times,1); % '- 9' to not to surpass the vector limit when you read the 10 items

for ind1 = 1:n_times
    random_number(ind1,:) = Data(index_random(ind1):index_random(ind1)+9)
end
```

Comment: You should pre-allocate `random_number` as `zeros(n_times,10)`. Also isn't it `+9` and not `+10` to get `10` elements?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929731/2586922), but avoids using cells and `arrayfun`, so it may be faster.

Let `Ns` denote the number of contiguous numbers you want (10 in your example), and `Nt` the number of times (100 in your example). Then:

```
result = Data(bsxfun(@plus, randi(numel(Data)-Ns+1, Nt, 1), 0:Ns-1)); %// Nt x Ns
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, close to @Luis, but with `cumsum` instead of `bsxfun`:

```
A = rand(1,1000); % The vector to sample
sz = size(A,2);
N = 100; % no. of samples
B = 10; % size of one sample
first = randi(sz-B+1,N,1); % the starting point for all blocks
rand_blocks = A(cumsum([first ones(N,B-1)],2)); % the result
```

This results in an N-by-B matrix (`rand_blocks`), each row of it is one sample.  Of course, this could be one-lined, but it won't make it faster, and I want to keep it clear. For small `N` or `B` this method is slightly faster. If `N` or `B` becomes very large then the `bsxfun` method is slightly faster. This ranking is not affected by the size of `A`.